# Error in navigating one page to another using Spring MVC framework?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to navigate from one page to another using spring MVC in my project.

I have two JSP page and one controller.
First page is welcome page which opens when i start the project using tomcat.
My project is able to show welcome page. But it can't find the mapping.

Welcome page code:

```
<a href="hello.html">Say Hello</a>
```

Second page code:

```
<body> ${message} </body>
```

Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        System.out.println(message);
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }

}
```

Servlet xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />

     <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
           <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
           <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>

        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
</beans>
```

Web xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: Define what happens *precisely*. If you get an error message, paste it completely.

Comment: Try to change the `@RequestMapping("/hello")` to `@RequestMapping("/hello.html")` and also add a request mapping for your controller class like @RequestMapping("/helloWorld") after this ensure that in the browser your final URL should be like this http://localhost:8080/appName/helloWorld/hello.html

Comment: `<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`  in your configuration you have given that your all the request should be like .html

Comment: user230391 Is the problem solved ??

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
public class HelloWorldController {
@RequestMapping("/hello.html")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
    String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
    System.out.println(message);
    return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
   }
}
```

Now try hitting `http://localhost:port/appName/helloWorld/hello.html` if you see correct page then change the link as following

`<a href="/appName/helloWorld/hello.html">Say Hello</a>`